# XML Reader and IDN urls in PHP

Tags: php

I have an IDN url.
If I put it into an XMLReader as is, I get two warnings

```
Warning: XMLReader::open(http://www.джумла-тест.рф/master/article-category-blog?format=feed&type=rss): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\joomla-cms2\libraries\joomla\feed\factory.php on line 44

Warning: XMLReader::open(): Unable to open source data in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\joomla-cms2\libraries\joomla\feed\factory.php on line 44
**Error. Feed could not be retrieved.**
```

If I urlencode I get one

```
Warning: XMLReader::open(): Unable to open source data in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\joomla-cms2\libraries\joomla\feed\factory.php on line 44
**Error. Feed could not be retrieved.**
```

If I change it to punycode it works, but is that the right way?

Update:
I want to add to this that I think maybe the problem is earlier, in that the query is not returning the correct idn url.  But I'd still like to know if xmlreader in php can handle the idn urls assuming I can get them from the database correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion with other developers, it seems like the answer is "Yes you need to send the request as punycode."